# html move content from one frame to another

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, frame, frameset

So I have put together a locally run web page which currently has 2 frames - one a nav bar and one for content which is defined with links in the nav bar. This is being run in internet explorer 8 and unfortunately has to stay this way.

I won't get into the details of what I want to achieve in the long run as this is more of a proof of concept, but I'm wondering; would it be possible to have 3 frames - one a nav bar, and 2 content frames and a link in the nav bar which would move the contents of the first contents frame to the second contents frame.

I have tried using a crude function written in the nav bar page:

```
var theContent =  window.parent.document.getElementById("frame2").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

window.parent.document.getElementById("frame3").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = theContent;
```

However I am getting a cross domain error (access is denied). Is there an alternative way of moving the content from one frame to another?

As a side note I'm not looking to just load the same website in the second frame as I realise you can just set href of the second frame to that of the first; I actually want to transfer a session to another frame.

The end goal would be a sort of tabbed interface where you could switch between frame sessions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"*transfer a session to another frame*" would be more than just copying the current HTML code from one frame to another; and loading the page again would be more close to it imho.

Yet, the SOP will prevent any access to the third-party pages loaded in your interface, so I don't think there is much feasible. If it helps, you rather should try to move around the whole frames instead of their contents.